# /etc/my.cnf conflict when trying to install mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

I am pretty new with Linux, so please be patient :)

Ran into database connection problem and decided to reinstall/update mysql

Now I get the following error message:

Transaction check error:
file /etc/my.cnf from install of mysql-community-server-8.0.31-1.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package MariaDB-common-10.2.37-1.el7.centos.x86_64

I tried to rename my.cnf to my.cnf.bak, but it does not work.

Comment: Do you want to have both new MySQL and existing MariaDB on your host? If not then uninstall mariaDB previously.

Comment: @Akina

I don't really care which one, as long as it works. :)

So, I tried to remove mariadb, but it seems it's gone already?

`# yum remove mariadb mariadb-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, remove-with-leaves, replace
No Match for argument: mariadb
No Match for argument: mariadb-server
No Packages marked for removal`

Comment: @JohanTwelli It would be helpful if you share the commands you used to "reinstall/update" mysql